# Question : "that integrate" or "integrating"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I'm wondering, for a formal document, which sentence is the more correct

1. We want to create a unique ecosystem around the players **integrating** aspects of xxx, yyy and zzz
2. We want to create a unique ecosystem around the players **that integrate** aspects of xxx, yyy and zzz

Also, if number 2 is the best, would you use "which integrate" instead of "that integrate"?

Comment: (2) is better because it makes it clear that it's the ecosystem and not the players doing the integrating - BUT as 'ecosystem' is singular, it must be _that integrates_. You could use _which_ instead if you preferrred.

Comment: Thank for you help :)

Comment: If you go with "integrating", put a comma here "...players, integrating..."